# Deserialize response body from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, dotnet-httpclient

This code is sample response body from an api.

```
message_type=incoming&mobile_number=639181234567&shortcode=29290123456&request_id=5048303030534D415254303030303032393230303032303030303030303133323030303036333933393932333934303030303030313331313035303735383137&message=This+is+a+test+message&timestamp=1383609498.44
```

Is there a way to place the response body to the properties of an entity like this one?
Or something like deserialize the response body?

```
public class SampleApi
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }

    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string ShortCode { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string SecretKey { get; set; }

    //Start From Reply Api

    public string RequestId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this Chikka by chance? If so it looks like the request body is formatted like this, not the response body (those appear to be JSON), and if so you'd probably be more interested in serializing your custom object to a request body that deserializing it from a response...no?

Comment: Yes this reponse is from Chikka Api, Specifically form Chikka receive Api. I will receive this reponse then I will use the code answer by Eser to deserialize it.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom deserializer for it

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string resp) where T : new()
{
    var nameValuePairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(resp);
    var obj = new T();
    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                   .ToDictionary(p => p.Name.Replace("_","") , p => p, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    foreach(var key in nameValuePairs.AllKeys)
    {
        var newkey = key.Replace("_", "");
        if (props.ContainsKey(newkey))
            props[newkey].SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(nameValuePairs[key], props[newkey].PropertyType));
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and use as

```
string response = "message_type=incoming&mobile_number=639181234567&shortcode=29290123456&request_id=5048303030534D415254303030303032393230303032303030303030303133323030303036333933393932333934303030303030313331313035303735383137&message=This+is+a+test+message&timestamp=1383609498.44";
var sampleApi = Deserialize<SampleApi>(response);
```

Comment: I added null for the third parameter like this one `props[newkey].SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(nameValuePairs[key], props[newkey].PropertyType), null);` to make it work. any way thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom message format (not XML or JSON), so the only way would be to split the string on the "&" and then split each name/value pair on the "=" and map it to your class properties.

Comment: So if there is no library to handle this format, I guess I will do as you said, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in the controller you can use your type directly

```
    ActionResult YourApiAction(SampleApi sampleApi)
    {
        var allMapped = sampleApi.MappMessage();
        ....allMapped.MessageType...
    }
```

but the names in the message must be the same name like in youy type. 
message_type --> should be MessageType and so on.
Then the magic serializes your message directly in your type.

for my comment:

```
 class SampleApi
 {
    string message_type { get; set; }
    string MessageType { get; private set }

    SampleApi MappMessage()
    {
       MessageType = message_type;
       return this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it also a good idea, but the other api who call my api is came from different source so i cant change it from message_type-->MessageType. But if you have an idea to place a data annotation in properties to a class to map the response (something like this one `
[MapResponse="message_type"]
public string MessageType { get; set; }`), it will be a good idea also.

Comment: rename the properties in your class SampleApi.message_type. Or add the message Propertie names to the class. then write a method getMessage where you mapp the message properties to your Propertie names

Comment: It also a good idea(even it does not look good in resharper's view) and I can use it also for other situation. Thanks!